# How to connect my Railway API on a subdomain in Hostinger

Tags: dns, cloud, subdomain, host, railway

Basically, I created a subdomain on Hostinger, and after creating it, I replaced the IP of this subdomain to point to the IP of my API on Railway

Railway:
[image: Railway]

Hostinger:
[image]

However, when testing the URL in Postman, I end up receiving the following response, which seems to me like it didn't work. Did I do something wrong?
[image]

Comment: I'm thinking it might be something in my NestJS API, some configuration to work with subdomains. I'm researching it

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was indeed in the NestJS API. I needed to add the correct host in relation to the subdomain. The controller notation looked like this:

```
@Controller({ host: process.env.SUB_DOMAIN_URL, path: 'user'})
```